# Filtering output by OR condition in Linux

Tags: linux, grep

is there some way to filter output of command by OR condition in Linux?
There is filtering by AND condition with grep in way like:

```
ls -l | grep "^a" | grep "z$"
```

That says: list all files that beggins with "a" AND ends with "z" (so there is shorter way to write this: grep "^a\.*z$", but it is not matter).
Is there some way to perform test by OR condition?
For example: files that starts exactly with "xen" OR files that ends exactly with ".rpm". But exactly, not something like:

```
grep "[xen]{0,3}\.*[.rpm]{0,4}"
```

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU `grep` accepts `\|` as an OR operator in regular expressions, so you could use

```
grep '^xen\|\.rpm$'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `egrep` (which is an alias for `grep -E`) to use extended regular expressions in the search pattern like this:

> egrep '^xen|\.rpm$'

Note that `[xen]{0,3}` means: Look for a string that has a length between 0 and 3 and consists of any combination of the characters x, e and n.